# Return HTML String in ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, ajax

I am making ajax call to return an HTML string, but its returning complete HTML of current page, I want to get only the HTML I am making in webmethod
This is my code

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: 'MyPage.aspx/GetData',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: 'html',
                success: function (data) {
                  $("#mydiv").find(".table tbody").append(data.toString());                 
                },
                error: function (data, errorThrown) {
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });
```

Asp:

```
        [WebMethod]
        public static string GetData()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                                sb.Append("<tr>");
                    sb.Append("<td style='width: 125px' id='categ'>Testing</td>");
                    sb.Append("<td style='width: 80px'>" + DateTime.Now+ "</td>");
                    sb.Append("<td style='width: 80px'>Sample Product</td>");                    
                    sb.Append("</tr>");

            return sb.ToString();
      }
```

I also tried this

```
 dataType: 'json',
```

but its giving parse error.
This is my HTML

```
<div id="mydiv">
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                 Category
            </th>
            <th>
                Date
            </th>
            <th>
                Product
            </th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to you `.d` with the object you received that is data. You need `data.d` instead of `data`

```
success: function (data) 
{
     $("#mydiv").find(".table tbody").append(data.d));                 
},
```

Comment: Did you try to log data using console.log(data)

Comment: What do you mean , it returns complete Html? please provide the response.

Comment: @SuperHornet complete HTML means,its returning the HTML of MyPage.aspx

Comment: I think you have problem with selector, can you show us the html you have?

Comment: Your jQuery code seems alright, check it here, http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/a4nM3/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$("#mydiv").find(".table tbody").append(data));
```

Comment: I am getting HTML of my page in data, I want only HTML that I am sending from my web method

Comment: data is supposed to be what you send by the web method, not anything more.

Comment: Yes that's the problem I am not getting what I am sending from WebMethod :)

Comment: you need to do server side debugging

Comment: @SyedSalmanRazaZaidi Then you have to debug it from the point which specifies that your Web Method is getting ran or not.